# Why isn't CSS rules applied on embedded SVG symbols?

Tags: css, svg, mouseover

Here is a simple version of CSS rules with hover and it is working fine:
https://codepen.io/hbi99/pen/oNvaEZK

...however if I try to use the SVG as symbol and reference it with USE-tag; the CSS rules for **:hover** is ignored. See this example:
https://codepen.io/hbi99/pen/pozxaea

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
 <symbol id="box" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <style>
   .test {
    fill: #f00;
    opacity: 0.35;
   }
   .test:hover {
    fill: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
   }
  </style>
  <rect class="test" x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150"/>
 </symbol>
</svg>

<svg><use href="#box"></use>
```

Any idea why the second example isn't working as intended?
I am testing this on Chrome (v76)

Comment: **1.** Take the styles outside the `<symbol>`. **2.** Apply the styles to the element you are hovering, i.e. the use element. You are not hovering the symbol.

Comment: As I've commented before: you are not hovering the `.test` since the `.test` is part of the symbol.  You need to apply the styles to the element you are hovering

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked that should not work, also works. But the code snippet you included in the question does not work since you use a class selector but don't use the class in the SVG image.

Add `class="utc-bar"` to the `<rect>` element and it works fine.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
 <symbol id="box" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <style>
   .utc-bar {
    fill: #f00;
    opacity: 0.35;
   }
   .utc-bar:hover {
    fill: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
   }
  </style>
  <rect class="utc-bar" x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150"/>
 </symbol>
</svg>

<svg><use href="#box"></use>
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. I edited my original post. Though, when I try your code in Chrome 76, it doesn't work for me. In Firefox it does work as expected. Are you testing in Chrome? If yes, which version? Thanks in advance